# Is there a way to ignore remaining php tags but to still output anything outside of php tags?

Tags: php, html

I would like to have a conditional statement that, on the condition being true, ignores the rest of php code but still outputs everything that is outside of php tags.

In essence, I would like to have a 'similar' behaviour to `die()` function but I would still like the remaining content outside of the php tags to be printed.

For example, considering the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
if ($condition) {
    /* Ignore the rest of this php tag
     * and remaining php tags, but output
     * everything else. */
}
// do something
?>
<p>Message 1</p>
<?php
// do something
?>
<p>Message 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

when `$condition` has a truthy value, any remaining php statements (the rest of the first php tag and the second php tag) will be ignored but both paragraphs will still be printed.

Is there a function/way to accomplish this, or do I need to restructure my code?

Thanks

Comment: No way to do that, you need to restructure your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a simple bool variable to decide if you want that logic to execute, assuming that your 'do something comments' are unique, that is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            $doSomethingElse = false;
            if ($condition) {
                $doSomethingElse = true;
                /* 
                 * Ignore the rest of this php tag
                 * and remaining php tags, but output
                 * everything else. 
                 */
            } else {
                // do something
            }
        ?>
        <p>Message 1</p>
        <?php
            if($doSomethingElse)) {
                // do something else
            }
        ?>
        <p>Message 2</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For what I want to accomplish, `$doSomethingElse` would be initialized to `true` and changed to `false` inside the conditional statement. Other than that, it is really helpful, thank you.

Comment: would also consider using isset() on that variable, depending on the order of your includes/execution :), great stuff